# Yosemite 10.10.3 - New Files and Directories Not Showing in Finder

Tags: macos, finder

When I create a new file or directory, it does not dynamically appear in Finder. I need to manually relaunch the Finder.

Any tips on how to fix this? I know I can create an AppleScript to add a "relaunch" button to the Finder, but that's not really a solution.

Comment: It's beta software. As such, I think the best explanation for what's going on is " happens." :)

Comment: Seriously, though, I have no idea how to fix your issue, but you should definitely file a report through Feedback Assistant. If it's an issue with OS X and not with something specific you've done, Apple needs to deal with it before the final release.

Comment: I've heard people having the same issue with .1 & .2 of Yosemite too - something's definitely running slower in the Finder than it did in Mavericks. As a matter of interest, do you have an HD or SSD? I'm almost of the mind that Yosemite pretty much demands an SSD these days.

Comment: What do you mean by HD vs SSD? (I feel like I should know this)

Comment: HD = Hard Drive as in a mechanical with rotational platters vs. SSD = Solid State Drive as in integrated circuits with semiconductor memory that functions as a disk drive.

Comment: How do I check which one I have?

Comment: In a Terminal: `diskutil info /dev/disk0 | grep 'Device / Media Name'`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not a proper fix but it might help with finding one! If you disable "Show icon preview" in View Options, the problem disappears. You have to click on any other folder and then again on the original one for it to update.